# How to make VLC File Picker style using default system file picker style?

Tags: vlc

I'm using VLC Media Player version 3.0.11.1, i'm installing VLC With APT, the file picker did not use default system file picker, even i'm Force Window Style to System Default Style ([VLC File Picker Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaTjv.png)). This is the default system file picker ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuUNk.png)). How i can make my VLC Using default system file picker style?

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, VLC GUI still uses GTK2. So the VLC file picker is GTK2 style, while system file picker is GTK3 style. I'm afraid not much can be done about it.

Comment: But, why if i'm install VLC using flatpak it's using system default file picker style?

Comment: I haven't used Flatpak, but as far as I know, Flatpak applications - similarly to snap ones - "carry" all the required external components with themselves, they don't rely on what's already in the system. That may be the difference. It is also possible that the version you install via Flatpak is a newer one than the one available via .deb package and already changed to GTK3.